# How to pass unknown variables to another function in R

Tags: r, function, arguments

I am writing a function, which generates a Heatmap using some input data, but performs some transformations beforehand. To generate the actual heatmap, I am using `ComplexHeatmap::Heatmap`, which offers a huge variety of options to modify the heatmap. I would like to give the user the opportunity to directly specify arguments of the `ComplexHeatmap::Heatmap` through my functions.

Right now I am using something which looks like this:

```
library(ComplexHeatmap)

mat = matrix(rnorm(100), 10)
rownames(mat) = paste0("R", 1:10)
colnames(mat) = paste0("C", 1:10)


test_fun <- function(mat, ...){
  args = list(...)
  print(args)
  p <- ComplexHeatmap::Heatmap(mat,
               show_row_names = args$show_row_names)
  return(p)
}



test_fun(mat, show_row_names=F)
```

This works fine, but lets say if the user wants to change the `show_column_names` argument of `ComplexHeatmap::Heatmap`. This would result in an error because I did not explicitly defined `args$show_column_names`. It seems very tedious to do this manually for every single argument that `ComplexHeatmap::Heatmap` offers and I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this. Ideally and what I ultimately would like is, that `ComplexHeatmap::Heatmap` would use its default argument's, but the user can "overwrite" them if he/she specifies them in the `test_fun` function.

I thought something like this might work, but unfortunately it doesnt.

```
test_fun <- function(mat, ...){
  args = list(...)
  print(args)
  p <- ComplexHeatmap::Heatmap(mat, ...)
  return(p)
}



test_fun(mat, show_row_names=F, show_column_names=F)
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not particularly familiar with the package, but do you just want to:

```
test_fun <- function(mat, ...){
ComplexHeatmap::Heatmap(mat,...)
}
```

It seems like you do, for example we could get rid of the column names and the row_names by calling test_fun as so:

```
test_fun(mat, show_row_names=FALSE, show_column_names = FALSE)
```

The ellipsis or ... allows us to place an arbitrary number of 'arguments recognised by the ComplexHeatmap::Heatmap function' in our test_fun function.

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea why it did not work for me in the example above... Probably still had something loaded in my environment that prevented it.

Comment: Cool, I hadn't actually tried your function as I took your word that it wasn't working. It worked fine for me, just a bit of superfluous code perhaps. Mind marking this as solved/answered?